# How to get the name of the virtual environment to show up in VS code terminal

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, virtual-environment, anaconda3

When I run python code in the integrated terminal with Powershell, the name of the virtual environment does not show up. Everything worked but it does not show that it is using the specified Conda Environment. How to fix this, please?
I tried

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process`

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just had to do `conda init`

[source](https://cookiecutter-research-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/anaconda-on-windows.html)